# pass object to IN Operator without single quote

Tags: sql, asp.net

```
Select * from table_A WHERE name in (@nameObj)
```

My issue is I am passing this object from code behind as

```
@nameObj = "'" + "john" + "'" + "," + "'" + "joseph" + "'"
```

So I want my final query like this:

```
Select * from table_A WHERE name in ('john','joseph')
```

But it is giving query like this:

```
Select * from table_A WHERE name in ('''john'',''joseph''')
```

Comment: You should use sql parameters

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, can you show how to use parameters if, for example, you do not know beforehand how many names you want in the IN clause?

Comment: it will be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

This work for me

```
sql = $@" AND Office IN ('{string.Join("','", new string[] { "aa", "bb"})}')";
```

But you should pass this as sql parameter;

in sql query you have

```
AND Office IN (@datain)
```

and in call query

```
_dbContext.Offices.FromSql(sql,
                new NpgsqlParameter(
                     "@datain", 
                     $@"'{string.Join("','", new string[] {"aa", "bb"})}')")
                )
                .ToList();
```